# removing BerkeleyDB rows using Perl

Tags: database, perl

I have no experience with Perl or BerkelyDB. I have a huge BerleleyDB with a list of email and a unix timestamp. I need help to remove email with older timestamp , older than 100 days .

I have this section of Perl code

```
#!/usr/local/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin/perl

  use BerkeleyDB;

  my $filename = '/usr/local/assp/whitelist.bdb';
  my $dbh = new BerkeleyDB::Hash(
          -Filename => $filename)
          or die "Error opening $filename : $! $BerkeleyDB::Error\n";

 my $cursor = $dbh->db_cursor() ;
    while ($cursor->c_get($k, $v, DB_NEXT) == 0) {
        print "Key: " . $k . ", value: " . $v . "\n";

    }

### Close the Berkeley DB
untie $filename;
exit;
```

which shows all rows with a Key ($k) and a value ($v)

The result is something like this

```
Key: email1@gmail.com, value: 1578560300
Key: email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com, value: 1578643050
Key: email4@gmail.com, value: 1578643050
```

Anyone can help me to add Perl code to remove during the *while* execution above, all Key rows with unix timestamp value older more than 100 days ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `c_del` [as documented](https://metacpan.org/pod/BerkeleyDB#$status-=-$cursor-%3Ec_del(%5B$flags%5D)), i.e.

```
my $long_ago = time() - 100*24*60*60; # 100 days ago
...
while ($cursor->c_get($k, $v, DB_NEXT) == 0) {
    if ($v<$long_ago) {
        $cursor->c_del();
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not seem to work , no row is removed from db if I execute it. I receive no error, however no row is removed.

Comment: correction , it seems to work , however I do not understand why the bdb file size does not change it was 1310720 and it is 1310720 after the rows removal .

Comment: @gr68: this is a different question but have a look at [compact](https://metacpan.org/pod/BerkeleyDB#$status-=-$db-%3Ecompact($start,-$stop,-$c_data,-$flags,-$end);). Databases are usually not tightly packed and free everything immediately, they are optimized for performance not file size.

Comment: no way to reduce the size , however thank you for code it helped me a lot.